# Can I assign to the return value of member access operator?

Tags: c++, member-access

I've read that the Member Access Operators dot operator `.` and arrow operator `->` return values:

> The arrow operator requires a pointer operand and yields an lvalue. The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue; otherwise the result is an rvalue.

This is from C++ Primer 5 edition.

So I imagine I can assign a value whenever a non-const lvalue is the return of their expression e.g:

```
struct foo {
    int x_;
    const int y_ = 17; ;
    void bar() { cout << "bar()" << endl;}
}f, *pf;

pf = &f;

(pf->bar()) = 75; // error
cout << f.x_ << endl;
(f.bar()) = 12;// error
(f.x_) = 23;
cout << "f_x: " << f.x_ << endl;
(pf->y_) = 34;// error
```

I am confused about assigning to the return value of arrow operator. Above it is said that `->` always returns an lvalue but it fails if I try to assign to that value.

- Can anyone explain to me the paragraph above from the C++ book. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `operator->`. Its just that you are assigning to the result of a `void` function and to a `const int`. You would get the same thing if you changed `pf->` for `f.` everywhere.

Comment: Thats happens because your `bar()` is a function and your `y_` is a const, you cannot change that values.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: What does it mean "arrow operator always returns an lvalue" ? or this is a mistake in the book?

Comment: @AdamMenz It means just what it says. That `operator->` always returns an [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue). Edit : Though how old is that quote? I'm not sure if that's true.

Comment: `pf->bar` evaluates to the address of the function `bar`. `pf->bar()` evaluates to the return type of the function `bar`, which is this case is `void`. You can't assign a value of 75 to that, sorry. But if the function had returned a reference to a modifiable integer, for example, then `(pf->bar()) = 75;` would have compiled (with or without the additional parentheses).

Comment: What's with all those parentheses? `(pf->bar()) = 75`, `(f.bar()) = 12`, `(f.x_) = 23` etc. They are completely unnecessary, and will drive your colleagues mad. And if your intention is to drive your colleagues mad, why not go the whole hog? `(pf->bar()) = (75)`, `(f.bar()) = (12)`, `(f.x_) = (23)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Above it is said that -> always returns an lvalue but it fails if I try to assign to that value.

This is about member variables, not functions.  `bar` returns `void` so you can never assign to it.  `x_` works since it gives you an integer lvalue expression.  `y_` fails because it is `const`, and you can't assign to a `const` variable.

So, in

```
foo bar;
foo* f = &bar;
f->x_;
f->y_;
```

both member accesses yield an lvalue expression.  In

```
foo f;
f.x_;
f.y_;
```

you again have lvalues since `f` is an lvalue.  However, in

```
foo{}.x_;
foo{}.y_;
```

both member accesses are rvalues since `foo{}` is an rvalue.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is really so clear and instructive. In fact I know I can't assign to an rvalue fro example from a function returns by value. But now you made things so clear and I understood the paragraph in the book. Thank you again.

Comment: So as in your example `foo{}.x_ = 10;` is incorrect because the dot operator here returns rvalue because the object on which it is called is an rvalue not lvalue. But `f.x_ = 2;` is correct becuase `f` is an lvalue and `x_` . is also a modifiable lvalue thus the assignment succeeds.

Comment: @AdamMenz Correct.

Comment: Thanks for your time and elaboration and being such constructive person.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I assign to the return value of member access operator?

If the left hand operand of the operator is an lvalue, and if the member is assignable and non-const, then yes. In other cases, no.

> ```
> (pf->bar()) = 75; // error
> ```

You are not assigning to the result of the member access operator. You are invoking a member function. The result is whatever the function returns. The function returns `void`, which is not assignable.

> ```
>  (pf->y_) = 34;// error
> ```

You're attempting to assign a const object. That is ill-formed even if the expression is an lvalue.